# How to build gradle project completely offline?

Tags: gradle

I have a project git clone --depth 1 --branch 3.0.0 https://github.com/bobbylight/RSyntaxTextArea.git the build.gradle is:

```
group 'com.fifesoft'
version '3.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
// NOTE: Local Java 8:  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home

allprojects {

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots'
        }
    }

    wrapper {
        gradleVersion = '5.0'
    }
}

subprojects {

    apply plugin: 'java'
//    apply plugin: 'checkstyle' // TODO: Figure out why checkstyle stopped finding suppressions file with gradle 5
    //apply plugin: 'findbugs' //TODO: Have FindBugs ignore generated code

//    checkstyle {
//        toolVersion = '8.15'
//    }

/*
    tasks.withType(FindBugs) {
        reports {
            xml.enabled = false
            html.enabled = true
        }
    }
*/
    dependencies {
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }

    compileJava {
        sourceCompatibility javaVersion
        targetCompatibility javaVersion
        options.debug = true
        options.debugOptions.debugLevel = 'source,vars,lines'
        options.compilerArgs << '-Xlint:deprecation' << '-Xlint:unchecked'
    }
}
```

which must be built in offline environment. For that I need to pre-download sources and dependencies, store them on disk, then go offline, then run "gradle build". Please tell me how to modify configs to perform this task?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First - copy ~/.gradle/caches to $PROJECT_DIR/gradle then go offline and run the following bash script:

```
cp -r ./gradle/caches ~/.gradle
gradle --offline build
```